# How to use max operator in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to know how to use the $max operator for the following problem:
Suppose this is the data given:
{

"_id" :                     ,

"attributes":

{
    "value1":10,

```
"value2":50,

"value3":70,

"value4":25,

"value5":50,

"value6":20
```

}
}

I have provided one set of JSON. There are multiple JSON.
I want to find the maximum value for value3 = 70 in this case and get a "_id" corresponding to it which can be passed in next query as a parameter.

I have tried it but i am unable to get a correct answer.

db.collection.group(

```
{"_id": $null , {"attribute.value1":true},
    reduce: function(obj,prev) { 
        if (prev.maxValue < obj."attribute.value") { 
            prev.maxValue = obj."attribute.value"; 
        }  
    },
initial: { maxValue: 0 }}
```

);

Comment: attributes is a list of  embedded documents ?

Comment: I have modified the question.

Comment: From this description it is still hard to understand your schema and what query you need to do. 
What I got is that your documents have a field named 'attributes' which is a list having embedded documents: `[
            {
                "id":1 ,
                "value":10
            },
              
            {
                "id":2,
                "value":50
            },
              
            {
                "id":3,
                "value":70
            },
     
    ]`, and for each document you need to find max value from attributes? am I correct?